# Saving photo in different location

Tags: android

In my app, I need to take a photo, then send it via RestApi with other data. I want to store this photo in a different location to process it in the future. My code:

```
private void TakePictureAfterScan() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    TAKEN_PHOTO = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, TAKEN_PHOTO);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, ACTIVITY_CODE_REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), PICTURE_PHOTO_DIR);

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in 'onActivityResult' method (which is empty right now for tests), there are already two .jpg files saved in the device:

- In DCIM/Camera folder
- In my temporary folder

The problem is, both files have different names. I do not need and do not want files from DCIM/Camera folder. Is there any simple way to save taken a photo only in my temporary folder?

Comment: after you have copied the file, you will have to delete it from the DCIM folder.

Comment: How to delete file from DCIM folder inside onActivityResult method ? Files from DCIM and my folder has diffrent names.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this .

```
 File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), PICTURE_PHOTO_DIR);
```

use this..

```
 File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "folder name" + ImageName;);
```

Comment: This code dont work. Only change is that application save file only in DCIM/Camera folder.